# How do I import browserified scripts into a service worker using Chrome extension manifest version 3?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am working on a google extension and trying to import [boilerpipe](https://github.com/xissy/node-boilerpipe#readme) on my background.js file (for simplicity I will show an example with 'unique' lib instead).

manifest.json file:

```
"background": {
  "service_worker": "background.js",
  "type": "module"
},
```

I run `browserify main.js -o bundle.js`
(uniq is installed using npm)

main.js file:

```
var unique = require('uniq');
module.exports = unique;
```

background.js file:

```
import * as module from './bundle.js';

console.log('module', module.unique);


module.unique is undefined.
```

what is the correct why to import a browserified lib?

Comment: Your bundle.js is not a ES module so you can't import it natively. You can simply rename to background.js and use directly. Alternatively, use importScripts('bundle.js').

Comment: I added this code on background.js,
try {
    importScripts('./bundle.js');
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
but received this exception:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': Module scripts don't support importScripts().

Comment: Remove `, "type": "module"` from manifest.json.